# What were to happen if I short-circuited electricity generated by a power plant to the Earth?

Tags: power, ground, short-circuit, earth

I'm not sure how to word this better, so I hope this makes sense. Let's say theoretically that I connected a cable from the hot side of the power lines that run along the road to a stake in the ground, essentially short-circuiting electricity from the power plant to the Earth. What would happen? What would be the risks and hazards of this?

Comment: This would make a great XKCD what if. https://what-if.xkcd.com/

Comment: Not quite your question.. but there is a concept called Single-wire earth return where the Return from the load is via the earth. Had a problem with electrocuting cattle standing over the return path if I remember correctly.

Comment: It's the power grid earth isolated? If so I think nothing extreme will happen. Besides that, I think local power distribution stations will detect these kinds of conditions and shut of the power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [Single Wire Earth-Return](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-wire_earth_return) systems, the earth is used as the return wire.

If the soil conditions, hydrogeology etc. are up to it, you could get quite a large return current, which would blow breakers. If the soil is really dry (think desert and sand) then maybe not much current would flow (depending on whether your 'stake' is hundreds of meters long or not, and if it reaches any underground water).

Unless there's some great anomaly in the earth conditions (assuming homogeneity in the earth conditions) the volts per meter will not likely be very large, so I don't see much in the way of hazards. Maybe it would make the nightcrawlers (worms) come up out of the ground or raise zombies or something.

Comment: Actually the volts per meter *can* be large enough to worry about - see 'Step voltage'. This is a safety consideration around HV assets like transmission lines and substations.